# Jung2: How to implement displaying details of a node on mouse over of a Node?

Tags: java, graph, onmouseover, jung

I am looking for a way how to display details of a node (as a popup) on MouseOver. Unfortunately the Jung2 tutorial does not provide any information how to implement this kind of functionality. Could anybody share a code sample or point me to an example on the web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PluggableRendererDemo does this.

Answer (score 2):

use VisualizationViewer.setVertexToolTipTransformer

From the EdgeLabelDemo you can see a simple example is to use the built-in transformer:

```
vv.setVertexToolTipTransformer(new ToStringLabeller<Integer>());
```

You can also do with edges:

```
vv.setEdgeToolTipTransformer(new Transformer<Number,String>(){
    public String transform(Number e) {
        return "Edge:"+graph.getEndpoints(e).toString();
    }
});
```