# mouseEntered a JUNG2 vertex

Tags: java, mouse, jung

I am looking for the "correct" way to show a custom Component as a popup when I mouseover a Vertex in JUNG2.

This question is essentially the same as

[Jung2: How to implement displaying details of a node on mouse over of a Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075713)

but that person seems to be content with a simple tooltip popup, whereas I am not.

NOTE: I am currently using an implementation of [PluggableGraphMouse](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/control/PluggableGraphMouse.html) with a `MouseMotionListener` plugin which does something like this (I have `Note` objects as vertices):

```
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        Note note = graphVisualiser.getPickSupport().getVertex(getGraphLayout(), e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (note != null && note != lastMouseOverNote) {
            lastMouseOverNote = note;
            // my handling code here
        }
    }
```

It works when I mouse over a vertex, and I can also expand on the above to turn off the popup when the mouse goes away, but I am concerned that this approach is incredibly inefficient: it is essentially checking to see if I'm mousing over a vertex every time the mouse moves.

I'd rather have a Listener approach - is there a way to register `mouseEntered`/`mouseExited` event to the vertices? (from what I can tell, this is all happening through raw painting and there is no Component that I could register with).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be done, because the vertices are being drawn as primitives and don't have listeners for mouse movements - only selection/deselection.